# excel document printing differently between users

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, formatting, vba

I have inherited an excel program built in vba that generates a document in a worksheet to be printed into pdf.

My problem is that with the exact same inputs I can get two different documents. The main differences is the line spacing between cells. For one user there might be 2 words that appear on the last line of the cell leaving no space between the cells while for another user might have all their words appear on the previous line and now has a line space between the two cells.

I have tried manually adding line break at the end of the cells to try to make sure that all cells have some spacing between the two but this has now caused a few users to get double line spacing between their cells.

I'm a little lost as to what might be causing this. All my users are running the same version of excel and since this is still in the testing phase are using the exact same inputs. Also we are all part of the same organization and I believe our environments are almost identical ( did not set up so no guarantee )

How do I go about to make sure that when my vba sends the worksheet the be printed as a pdf that it comes out identical for all my users.

```
Function RDB_Create_PDF(Myvar As Object, FixedFilePathName As String, _
    OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
Dim FileFormatstr As String
Dim Fname As Variant

    'Test to see if the Microsoft Create/Send add-in is installed.
    If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
         & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

        If FixedFilePathName = "" Then
            'Open the GetSaveAsFilename dialog to enter a file name for the PDF file.
            FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
            Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
                  Title:="Create PDF")

            'If you cancel this dialog, exit the function.
            If Fname = False Then Exit Function
        Else
            Fname = FixedFilePathName
        End If

        'If OverwriteIfFileExist = False then test to see if the PDF
        'already exists in the folder and exit the function if it does.
        If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
            If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Exit Function
        End If

        'Now export the PDF file.
        On Error Resume Next
        Myvar.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=Fname, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
        On Error GoTo 0

        'If the export is successful, return the file name.
        If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then RDB_Create_PDF = Fname
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Same font set as default? Same Printer?

Comment: Yes to the same font. and as for printer its all being done with print to pdf. I'll edit my question and paste the pdf generating code.

Comment: If you are seeing a different number of characters per line between users they must be using either a different font or a different typesize, or the width of the column is different . Could one set of users be using windows fonts and the others the matching postscript version?

Comment: The entire program is a self contained application in an excel file. All the worksheets but a few input fields have been locked down. The user does not have the choice to change fonts or text size.

Comment: The user can choose in Printer settings in Windows whether to use Truetype or Postscript fonts for some printers - it's independent of Excel and over rides any excel settings. My understanding is that if you print to pdf it uses your printer settings.